# Installing software on another partition

Tags: partition, virtualization

I'm looking for a way to install new software on my Mac without adding clutter to the system folder.
For example, installing `Android Studio` or `VirtualBox`, even when removing it from the Mac, there is a folder of each on the `~/Library` folder which has to be deleted manually.

I thought about using a Virtual Machine, but the performance on a virtual machine are not good enough.
I also thought about a new partition to the hard drive, but I guess some of the things are still going to be installed on the main partition with the OS.

Is there any good solution for this?

Comment: No solution Library just gets increased - you rarely uninstall stuff so not really an issue - if you want to go back to a state before install then you need to use VMs - some tools make an attempt to remove all bits installed but are not 100% accurate e.g. Hazel

Comment: ...and BTW `~/Library` is not the *system folder.* It is a part of your *user folder.* And as such applies only to your login and is accessible only to your login.

Comment: @mmmmmm Thanks, got it! I tried using VMs but the performance are not good enough.

Comment: @SteveChambers Thanks! I didn't knew, but I still don't want junk files to be there after uninstalling programs, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately there are s many places where files can be put especially for things like virtual box there is no certain way to delete unwanted files. Except possibly for San boxed apps who can only write to their container